# Which source control to use (for a lot of images file)?

Tags: php, version-control, image

I finally decide to give a source control a try with my existed project (since I will be hiring another new developer soon). I am pretty new to this area and I need recommendation which Source Control should I use to fix my current project.

I am developing Web Application which dealing with large number of pictures. Currently, we have over 500,000 pictures (large size picture and several thumbnails). I am using PHP which is not what I concern (since it is just only hundred of script files). **My major concern is with the large amount of picture.**

**NOTE:**
I just install VisualSVN. What do you think about SVN. Do you think it will fix to my requirement?

---

I got two votes to close this question. I did read the FAQ and I believe my question is perfectly fine.

> Stack Overflow is for professional and enthusiast programmers, people
>   who write code because they love it. We feel the best Stack Overflow
>   questions have a bit of source code in them, but if your question
>   generally covers …
>
> - a specific programming problem
> - a software algorithm
> - **software tools commonly used by programmers practical,**
> - answerable problems that are unique to the programming profession
>
> … then you’re in the right place to ask your question!

Comment: I don't agree with the vote to close as off-topic, and I don't agree with voting to close without providing an explanation for doing so.  However, I don't disagree that this question should have been closed as 'not constructive', as it is somewhat subjective and open-ended.  From the FAQ: "Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page."  Just because a question relates to software tools doesn't mean you can ask it here.

Answer (score 2):

- Stay away from legacy version control software such as CVS and SVN.
- Use one that you can easily host yourself, so that you don't end up paying way too much for simple storage.

I'd go with Mercurial (hg) which is very easy to set up, you can host it yourself and is very easy to use. An alternative is Git, which is pretty much the same although the commands and internals are different.

Another alternative that's often used in commercial organizations is Perforce. I don't have experience with it myself, but I've heard good things about it and I think it should be able to handle huge amounts of files.

Comment: Does Mercurial able to store large amount of file effectively? I do not mind with the storage since I will host it myself.

Answer (score 1):

If you are new to source control, I recommend that you go with SVN. I find SVN to be most straight-forward option. VisualSVN is a good choice, works well and it is free of charge. However, I would encourage you to checkout hosted SVN repositories such as [beasntalkapp.com](http://beanstalkapp.com/).

Comment: I will host SVN server on my own server. Thanks for advice.

Answer (score 0):

What is your reasoning for adding all the images to version control? Will they change often?

In my experience, adding alot of binary files to any version control system is bulky, but particularly SVN, since you'll be checking for changes on the server, and a file check for 500.000 files is not fun.

I'd recommend you store your images in a shared folder instead, for example on a samba share or similar, and change the pointers in your code to that folder, so all developers share the same images.

The PHP code on the other hand should definitely go into version control, my recommendation is Git, but Mercurial is a good option. SVN is a legacy system that I wouldn't recommend.

Answer (score 0):

Stay away from old versioning software especially Visual Source Safe!!! My advice would be to go with Git (and you have a free host at bitbucket.org as well as hosting mercurial but i've never used that one). github.com is only free for open source projects, bitbucket is also free for private repos but charges per extra user instead.

I've been using git now for about 4 months and it's brilliant. Sub version i found annoying and only used it briefly (was years ago and can't fully remember why i stopped using it - something to do with directory and file handling i think).

Git seems to be the latest one to get a good foothold and after using it it really is VERY flexible as well. I quite enjoy the rule that once you commit something to the repository - it's hard to accidentally remove it! Branching is also very fast compaired to alternatives and because it works by linking to the previous unchanged version instead of saving diffs and having to reapply them all it's quite small filesize wise and is VERY fast compaired to others. I also store about 3000 icons in it, 300 lines of code and about 500 php files + js libs, etc all in a single project and to be honest it's just as fast as when i first started with a few files!

You won't go wrong with Git - and use either github or bitbucket in the start as it's much easier to get started that way. You can always setup a repo yourself at a later date.